# Show Bluetooth settings page

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, settings, core-bluetooth

How do I show the Bluetooth settings page in objective-c?

So if the user has turned off Bluetooth (i.e. CoreBluetooth returns that the Bluetooth state is Powered Off), I'd like to have an option on an alertview to take them straight to the iPhone/iPad settings page to allow them to turn it on.

Comment: Unfortunately, since iOS 5.1, this isn't possible.

Comment: Really? The Nordic Semiconductor app "nRF Utility" can do it. Is that because it was developed with the 5.0 API?

Comment: I just checked and @SimonC is correct. The "nRF Proximity" app is still able to do this on iOS 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was done in iOS 5.0 and 5.0.1 using the "prefs:" URL scheme, but unfortunately Apple depreciated this scheme in 5.1 and this is no longer possible.

Comment: Ok thanks for this clarification.
I guess there is no other way at all of doing it? Seems odd that it was taken out, as allows an easier, quicker user experience.

Comment: Ahh. Just found that it appears that the framework asks for you abd deals with it anyway.